# RandomizedSearchCV reduces accuracy score drastically

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, cross-validation

when I am checking using RandomForestRegressor

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
r=RandomForestRegressor()
r.fit(X_train,y_train)
r.score(X_test,y_test)
```

I am getting  0.9746156332220394

But when I use RandomizedSearchCV

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 100, stop =1200, num = 12)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(5, 30, num = 6)]
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10, 15, 100]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 5, 10]

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
           'max_features': max_features,
           'max_depth': max_depth,
           'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
           'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf}

rf=RandomForestRegressor()

rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf,
                           param_distributions = random_grid,
                           scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                           n_iter = 10,
                           cv = 5,
                           verbose=2,
                           random_state=42,
                           n_jobs = 1)
rf_random.fit(X_train,y_train)
rf_random.score(X_test,y_test)
```

I am getting -14881793274.345808

So why did the accuracy scores behave soo poorly

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things wrong with your approach and assumptions:

**Issue 1: you are not measuring accuracy at all**

You have a regression task at hand. Hence, accuracy as a metric for correct *classifications* cannot be applied here. In fact, you are not measuring accuracy in any of your two cases.

**Issue 2: you are comparing different metrics**

The `score()` function of [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) does the following:

> Return the coefficient of determination R<sup>2</sup> of the prediction.

While the `score()` function of [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.score) does this:

> This uses the score defined by `scoring` where provided, and the `best_estimator_.score` method otherwise.

So in the first case, the R<sup>2</sup>  will be measured for the fitted `RandomForestRegressor`. In the second case, the negative Mean Squared Error (MSE) of the best-found estimator will be returned because you specified `neg_mean_squared_error` as the scoring metric.

In conclusion: **your comparison is invalid**

If you want to compare anything, either specify `scoring=r2` in your `RandomizedSeachCV` to compare the performance in regard to R<sup>2</sup>. Or use [`mean_squared_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error) to compute the MSE for the fitted `RandomForestRegressor` (but then keep in mind that the `RandomizedSearchCV` will return the negated MSE).

### Important note

You should also be aware that there is no guarantee that the best estimator found by `RandomizedSearchCV` will indeed perform better on your test set as the hyperparameters are cross-validated on the training set only and cannot take performance on the test set into account.

Comment: Yeah totally get it, Thanks for such a detailed explanation.